# Is the following statement on Jump Discontinuity correct?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have extracted this from MIT 18.01 lecture note:

> $$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\text{ for }(x<x_0)\text{ exists, and }\lim_{x\to x_0^-}\text{ for }(x>x_0) \text{ also exists, but they are NOT equal.}$$

I am a bit confused about the statements inside the parentheses. Should they be ($x > x_0$) and ($x<x_0)$ respectively?

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: I agree as well, isn't it redundant anyways?

Comment: Yes, they are swapped

Comment: Note that it is preferred that you do not embed an image, but instead rewrite the equation for users who cannot see embedded images and/or for search purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $x_0=2$
$$\lim_{x\to x_0^-}=0.9$$
$$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}=0.6$$

Both limits exist, but are not equal. This is what defines a jump discontinuity.

Also yes, you're correct.